# how to Save Cache in UIwebview?

Tags: swift, caching, webview, uiwebview, save

i want the webview to save cache to use later for the fast web load , this webview code that is written in swift 3
 can you help me with that

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController   {


@IBOutlet var webfirst: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlfirst = URL(string: "https://google.com")
    webfirst?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:urlfirst!))

}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: You want to use the cache later?

Comment: Yes to use later for the fast opening page

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the cachePolicy to .returnCacheDataElseLoad

`let urlfirst = URL(string: "https://google.com")
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:urlfirst!)
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
webfirst?.loadRequest(urlRequest)`